# Fedora over-current condition on port 1

Tags: linux, fedora

When I boot up my Fedora 18, I got this message > `[1.817675] hub 2-1:1-0: over-current condition on port 1` shown on the screen. Right after the Fedora logo disappear, and it is not yet boot into Fedora.

I was stuck now since I could not do anything, could anyone please advice what should I do for this problem? Before this issue was happened, I just download the necessary development package for LibreOffice using this command > `su -c 'yum-builddep libreoffice'`, I hope this is not the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a USB device is trying to draw too much current. Has nothing to do with LibreOffice. You may be able to see the message again with `dmesg`.

`lsusb -v` will show each device and their power draws. That should find it for you.help you track it down!

Comment: I was not in the console, and not able to type any input command.

Comment: Unplug every USB device except the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread from the lkml.org mailing list](http://lkml.org/lkml/2011/7/6/198) (Linux Kernel Mailing List):

> Subject   Re: Weird USB over-current messages in recent kernels...
>
> Hello.
>
> Alan Stern wrote:
>
> > > Seen during boot the last few days on my laptop:
> > >
> > > running 3.0.0-rc4-mmotm0622:
> > >       Jul  2 13:08:37 turing-police kernel: [    2.788108] hub 2-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 1
>
> ... ...
>
> > That message was added recently, which may explain why you haven't seen 
> >     it before.
>
> Wasn't there a similar dev_err() message before that patch that added this 
>   message (the previous message was printed on any over-current signal change)?
>
> > For more debugging, please collect a usbmon log for bus 2 or bus 6 (see 
> >     Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt).  In fact, you might try doing this for 
> >     an earlier kernel as well.
> >
> > It may be that your host controllers claim that an over-current
> >     condition exists when it really doesn't, or it may be that those ports
> >     are wired incorrectly and really do have an over-current condition.
>
> If it's EHCI driver, there's module option to suppress over-current 
>   checking, called 'ignore_oc'. It should help with bogus over-current signalling...

So if you determine that the message is benign you can disable it using the `ignore_oc` option.